# Back to Back Failing HDD's?

Tags: hard-drive

last year i purchased this PC, and this january i had a HDD get the "Hard disk failure is imminent."

I didn't diagnose the hdd, i simply considered it faulty, and bought a new one, the data in it wasnt relevant so it wasnt a big deal to me.

However, 45 days after replacing it, this new HDD got the same error.
So i went to diagnose it, and this is what i've gotten;

[Is this really a sign of a dying Drive?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6egA.png)

I don't really understand how S.M.A.R.T values work but.. the numbers don't look too off.

Should i have it replaced? Is there something in my PC that could be leading to these 'failing' drives?

thank you!

Comment: Unlikely anything in the PC is causing them to fail SMART. More likely you just got unlucky and got a bum drive. At 45 days it should be replaceable under warranty, assuming the warranty considers this a replaceable failure.

Comment: https://www.seagate.com/es/es/support/kb/internal-hard-drive-troubleshooter-006183en/

Comment: Why is the SMART attributes screenshot cut off at the bottom? Please add a screenshot of the entire list.

Answer (score 2):

Note the high [Spin retry count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9110). It could be something is keeping the HDD from quickly getting up to speed. Here are just a few possibilities:

- Low power when the PC is starting: It might be that the PSU is weak, or there is very high power demand on booting.
- Bad connections causing low power, e.g., a badly frayed wire.
- Operating in a very cold environment, causing parts to contract, creating friction and causing loss of alignment.
- Being brought inside from a cold environment (e.g., car trunk in winter) into a warmer, more *humid* place (e.g., a house), allowing moisture to condense on disk, causing head adhesion.

BTW, the disk might actually be fine, if an external issue is eliminated.

Comment: I hate that the RAW for 0xa is 0. if it wasn't a seagate util reading from a seagate disk, I'd consider that highly suspect. I wonder what other SMART tools show.